# Визуал студия подчеркивает ложные ошибки

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unreal-engine-4

Делаю игру на Unreal Engine. Подскажите из-за чего визуал студия может себя так ввести? Код полностью компилируется нормально без ошибок. Конечно и при таком раскладе дел можно работать, но уж больно мозолит глаза вот это вот...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Он компилируется в Visual Studio? Или отдельно.

Comment: можно скомпилировать код через анреал энжин, а можно и через визуалку